# C++ assigning a class to another class read error

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I'm trying to return a sub-image from a 5x7 matrix. I'm trying to retrieve the sub matrix (0,2,0,2). I've created a function get_Block which SHOULD return the values of the matrix to temp, however just getting:

> Exception thrown at 0x003B2A96 in Logo_Unscrambler.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

It's probably super simple but I'm mega tired and I can't see it. Here's the code:

Main:

```
int main() {
double* A = new double[5*7];
for (int i = 0; i < 5 * 7; i++)
{
    A[i] = i;
}

Matrix Ab(5, 7, A);
Matrix temp;

temp = Ab.get_Block(0, 2, 0, 2);
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << temp.get(k,i, 3);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Matrix.cpp:

```
    Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double *input_data)
    {
        "Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double *input_data is invoked";

_M = sizeR;
_N = sizeC;
_data = new double[_M*_N];

for (int i = 0; i < _M*_N; i++)
{
    _data[i] = input_data[i];
}
    }

    Matrix Matrix::get_Block(int start_row, int end_row, int start_coloumn, int end_coloumn)
    {
int rows = (end_row - start_row) + 1;
int columns = (end_coloumn - start_coloumn) + 1;
int ctr = 0;

double *temp_Data = new double[rows*columns];

for (int x = start_row; x < (rows + start_row); x++)
{
    for (int y = start_coloumn; y < (columns + start_coloumn); y++)
    {
        temp_Data[ctr] = get(x, y,rows);
        ctr++;
    }
}

Matrix block(rows, columns, temp_Data);
delete[] temp_Data;

return block;
    }

    double Matrix::get(int i, int j, int row_Count)
    {
return _data[(i*_N) + j];
     }
```

Comment: `Matrix::_data` should be initialized with new, but that's not your problem.  When I run your code, the error I get (of course) is that Matrix is undefined.  We'll need an example that compiles and illustrates the problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yeah I just changed that haha - whoops!